# OpenCV imread and getFundamentalMatrix

Tags: python, ruby, opencv

Cannot make this work:

```
img1 = cv::imread('glassL.jpg')
img2 = cv::imread('glassR.jpg')

img1g = cv::Mat.new
cv::cvtColor(img1, img1g, CV_BGR2GRAY);
img2g = cv::Mat.new
cv::cvtColor(img2, img2g, CV_BGR2GRAY);

F = cv::findFundamentalMat(img1g, img2g, cv::FM_RANSAC, 0.1, 0.99)
```

It throws this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (npoints >= 0 && points2.checkVector(2) == npoints && points1.type() == points2.type()) in findFundamentalMat, file /tmp/opencv-XbIS/opencv-2.4.8.2/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp, line 1103
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ropencv-0.0.15/lib/ropencv/ropencv_types.rb:10509:in `find_fundamental_mat': /tmp/opencv-XbIS/opencv-2.4.8.2/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp:1103: error: (-215) npoints >= 0 && points2.checkVector(2) == npoints && points1.type() == points2.type() in function findFundamentalMat (RuntimeError)
```

I am using `ropencv` (Ruby + FFI), but I tried with Python cv2 and got exactly the same error. I cannot find any documentation on this and I am lost. `checkVector(2)` returns `-1` on both grayscale and color images and I don't know how to convert them to make them work with `findFundamentalMat`. Help please.

Comment: If you are talking about [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findfundamentalmat) you have to pass Pint2f instead Mat as input and output array

Comment: Yes, but what I can't find on Internet is how to convert from the output of `imread` to the desired input of `findFundamentalMat` (Point2f vector as you say)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the images directly to the function of to compute the fundamental matrix and this is not correct. In the documentation, it says:

- points1 – Array of N points from the first image. The point coordinates should be floating-point (single or double precision).
- points2 – Array of the second image points of the same size and format as points1 .

Therefore, you cannot simply put the images. There is a full example [here](http://cs.ucf.edu/~ramin/opencv/fundamental_matrix_calculation.cpp) using OpenCV. But there is a nice explanation [here](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/Robust/example/index.html) step by step using matlab so you can understand which points are you going to use (such as harris corners).

Comment: I want to use the RANSAC method, so the first link doesn't work for me, and the second I don't know how to translate in OpenCV lingo, but I think I understand the point is first I have to find features with algorithms like `SIFT` and then pass the result to `findFundamentalMat`, not the entire image?

Comment: The opencv code is the same for both algorithms, to use RANSAC you just have to change the call from CV_FM_8POINT to CV_FM_RANSAC. The rest is the same

Comment: Are you saying you use 8 points for RANSAC too? `int numPoints =8;`